# Python Fuel-SDK with oAuth2.0

Tags: marketing-cloud

Has anyone used the Fuel-SDK, after the API endpoints have changed? I am using the Python library, made changes to the endpoint and was able to generate the token. When I am trying to do anything it pretty much returns the result as none. I am thinking maybe there are more changes, I need to make. Any help would be appreciated. I am attaching the sample code I am using.

I am trying to write a code snippet to copy all DE's from a BU to another BU, I am hoping this can be used to stand up a BU with a standard set of DE's as well. If anyone is using any tool for that, please chime in. I know it's actually two questions in one. Sorry about that.

```
import FuelSDK
myClient = FuelSDK.ET_Client(False,False)
dataextension = FuelSDK.ET_DataExtension()
dataextension.auth_stub = myClient
dataextension.props = {'Name' : 'SDKDataExtension', 'Description': 'SDK Created Data Extension'}
dataextension.columns= [{'Name' : 'Key', "FieldType" : "Text", "IsPrimaryKey" : "true", "MaxLength" : "100", "IsRequired" : "true"},{"Name" : "Value", "FieldType" : "Text"}]
results = dataextension.post()
```

Comment: There's an active [branch in the repo](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/tree/oauth2-support) that claims to add OAuth2 support. No clue when that'll be released.